# Freezed and Bloc cannot use copyWith or access state

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using Freezed together with Bloc, however I dannot directly access the current state or use the copyWith Method. It always just provide functions such as "map", maybeMap" or "when".

How cann I use copyWith or access state variables directly?

Here are some code snippets:
state.dart

```
part of 'keekz_form_bloc.dart';

@freezed
class KeekzFormState with _$KeekzFormState {
  const factory KeekzFormState({
    required Keekz keekz,
    required bool showErrorMessages,
    required bool isEditing,
    required bool isSaving,
    required Option<Either<KeekzFailure, Unit>> saveFailureOrSuccessOption,
  }) = _KeekzFormState;

  const factory KeekzFormState.initial() = Initial;
}
```

bloc.dart:

```
part 'keekz_form_event.dart';
part 'keekz_form_state.dart';
part 'keekz_form_bloc.freezed.dart';

class KeekzFormBloc extends Bloc<KeekzFormEvent, KeekzFormState>  {
  final IKeekzRepository _keekzRepository;
  KeekzFormBloc(this._keekzRepository) : super(Initial()) {
    on<Initialized>((event, emit) {
      emit(
        state.maybeMap(
            (test) => test.copyWith(isEditing: true, keekz: initialKeekz),
            orElse: () => state,
          ),
      );
    });
```

I am not sure if the test.copyWith is working. What when I jsut want to access a state variable? How can I for example just check state.isEditing == true?

Answer (score 0):

To directly access the variables you must use the abstract implementation of the sealed classes through cast:

```
bool checkState = (state as _KeekzFormState).isEditing
```

This could be an example validating the type of state that comes from the Bloc:

```
if(state is _KeekzFormState){

  (state as _KeekzFormState).copyWith(
     isEditing: true,
     isSaving: true
  );

  bool checkState = (state as _KeekzFormState).isEditing;

}
```

`state` is an implicit stateStreamable on the Bloc class extended that can be cast as the abstract class that contains the property you want to access, in this case it should be `_KeekzFormState`

`_KeekzFormState` is the private abstract class you assigned in your KeekzFormState const factory declaration of your keekz_form_state.dart file

But for this to make a bit of sense, you must first change the value of the isEditing property, I'm going to refactor a bit the code you've left in the problem description to be more clear:

```
part 'keekz_form_event.dart';
part 'keekz_form_state.dart';
part 'keekz_form_bloc.freezed.dart';

class KeekzFormBloc extends Bloc<KeekzFormEvent, KeekzFormState>  {
  final IKeekzRepository _keekzRepository;
    KeekzFormBloc(this._keekzRepository) : super(Initial()) {
      on<Initialized>(initializedCallback);
  }

  void initializedCallback(KeekzFormState event, Emitter<KeekzFormState> emit) async{

     if(state is _KeekzFormState){

       (state as _KeekzFormState).copyWith(
         isEditing: true,
         isSaving: true
       );
     }

     bool checkState = (state as _KeekzFormState).isEditing;
     emit(KeekzFormState.initial());

  }
}
```